# Calcular el promedio de fechas en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo que calcular el promedio de los días y dar la siguiente fecha:

[image: Captura de pantalla de registros de una tabla]

Y tiene quedar el siguiente resultado:

[image: Captura de pantalla de tres datos]

Éste es el enunciado de la pregunta:

[image: Captura de pantalla del enunciado (en inglés) de la pregunta]

La traduccion es:

> Escriba una consulta para devolver información sobre los hábitos del cliente. Predecirá cuándo ocurrirá la próxima compra en función del promedio de días entre pedidos por cliente.
>
> - Base de datos: StoreSample
> - Tablas involucradas: Pedidos, Clientes

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Exactamente a qué te refieres con "promedio de los días" y "dar la siguiente fecha"? ¿Podrías darnos los datos en formato de un INSERT de SQL para poder reproducir tu problema?

Comment: Espero que mi respuesta te sea de utilidad. Si algo no funciona házmelo saber. PD: Por favor, agrega la definición de la tabla y algunos datos de ejemplo a tu pregunta. Eso ayudará a reproducir tu problema y mostrarte el correcto funcionamiento de las sugerencias que te hagamos. PD: ¿Has borrado el comentario previo a éste?

Comment: hola ya puse una imagen de el ejercicio en si te agradecería mucho si me ayudas

Comment: ¿Podrías traducir la pregunta al castellano y evitar el uso de capturas de pantalla? Por favor, comparte la definición de la tabla (para conocer los tipos de cada campo) y los datos del problema. Gracias.

Comment: la traduccion es "Escriba una consulta para devolver información sobre los hábitos del cliente.  Predecirá cuándo ocurrirá la próxima compra en función del promedio de días entre pedidos por cliente.  Base de datos: StoreSample Tablas involucradas: Pedidos, Clientes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según lo veo, lo que tienes que hacer consta principalmente de 2 partes.

Primero, encontrar el promedio en días (estoy suponiendo que es un número entero, no 1.4 días, por ejemplo) entre órdenes para cada compañía. Y luego tomar la última orden de cada compañía y sumar ese tiempo promedio.

Acá va una query que logra eso:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT
        CompanyName,
        LastOrderDate,
        LAG(LastOrderDate) OVER(PARTITION BY CompanyName ORDER BY LastOrderDate) FechaAnterior,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CompanyName ORDER BY LastOrderDate DESC) RN
    FROM dbo.Tabla t
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT
        c.CompanyName,
        AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY,c.FechaAnterior,LastOrderDate)) PromedioDias
    FROM CTE1 c
    GROUP BY c.CompanyName
)
SELECT 
    c1.CompanyName,
    c1.LastOrderDate,
    DATEADD(DAY,c2.PromedioDias,c1.LastOrderDate) NexPredictedOrder
FROM CTE1 c1
JOIN CTE2 c2
    ON c1.CompanyName = c2.CompanyName
WHERE c1.RN = 1
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tras la última edición en la que agregas (en inglés) las preguntas exactas, podemos calcular el intervalo entre pedidos con la siguiente fórmula:

```
Intervalo medio = (Máximo - Mínimo) / (Número - 1)
```

Es obvio que esta fórmula solo vale para 2 o más registros. En caso contrario no es posible averiguar el intervalo.

La predicción sería ese intervalo sumado al último pedido:

```
Predicción = Máximo + Intervalo medio
```

Podemos hacer uso de la conversión numérica si tus campos son de tipo `DATETIME`. Aunque puedes considerar la conversión a `INTEGER` (para que no considere la hora), te recomiendo la conversión a `FLOAT` (para que tenga en cuenta la hora).

Aquí tienes un ejemplo del SQL necesario:

```
SELECT
  companyname,
  CAST((
    MAX(CAST(LastOrderDate AS FLOAT))
    + (
      MAX(CAST(LastOrderDate AS FLOAT))
      - MIN(CAST(LastOrderDate AS FLOAT))
    ) / (COUNT(*) - 1)
  ) AS DATETIME) LastOrderDate
FROM
  tabla
GROUP BY
  companyname
HAVING
  COUNT(*) > 1
```

Puedes ver el funcionamiento en línea en el siguiente enlace:

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/70c394/1

En el ejemplo que enlazo tenemos las siguientes fechas de pedidos:

| companyname | LastOrderDate |
| --- | --- |
| prueba | 2022-01-02T12:20:30Z |
| prueba | 2022-01-03T12:20:30Z |
| prueba | 2022-01-04T12:20:30Z |
| otro | 2022-01-02T15:20:30Z |
| otro | 2022-01-05T15:20:30Z |
| último | 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z |

Como se puede observar hay una media de un día entre pedidos con el cliente *prueba*, por lo que el siguiente pedido debería ser al día siguiente del último. Con el cliente *otro* hay tres días entre pedidos y al cliente *último* no se le puede calcular la previsión por no tener suficientes datos:

| companyname | LastOrderDate |
| --- | --- |
| prueba | 2022-01-05T12:20:30Z |
| otro | 2022-01-08T15:20:30Z |

Comment: El fiddle no parece dar el resultado esperado, la verdad

Comment: ¿En qué falla @Lamak? Sale la fecha promedio de las tres introducidas y la fecha siguiente a la mayor.

Comment: Falla en más de un punto. No muestra la fecha última fecha, sino la anterior; y además simplemente estás sumando un día a la última fecha, cuando el ejercicio pregunta sobre predecir la siguiente compra en base al promedio de días entre compras...no un número fijo

Comment: @Lamak, estoy editando mi respuesta. En su pregunta original no había nada de lo que dices. Además, en la edición de la que hablas, la pregunta está en inlgés.